# Copy images to one single image file

Tags: c++

I have 3 png images:

1.png
2.png
3.png

i want to copy all the three images into one png file like this

**one.png:**

```
****************
*              *
*              *
*              *
*    1.png     *
*              *
*              *
*              *
*              *
****************

****************
*              *
*              *
*              *
*    2.png     *
*              *
*              *
*              *
*              *
****************

****************
*              *
*              *
*              *
*    3.png     *
*              *
*              *
*              *
*              *
****************
```

how can you do that in c++ on mac???

Comment: You mean you want to stitch the images together?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you get a copy of libpng from here: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

That will take care of all the decoding and encoding for you.  Then all you have to do is read the three files, stitch them together, and write the results back out.